# Get all stock quantities given one product

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, stock, multi-source-inventory, manage-stock

These are the stocks I have

[image: stock]

On my export this is what i'm getting, as you can see (for re and re_pro which belong to the same website) the quantity is fine , but the salable qty is a merge of both; that's why i'm trying to get back to the real quantity

```
source_code,sku,status,quantity,sku_franchise,name,decaffeinato,salable_qty
default,3421,1,1.0000,,"Container",,"Default Stock : 1"
source_bl,3421,1,0.0000,,"Container",,"Stock BL : 0"
source_gf,3421,1,0.0000,,"Container",,"Stock GF : 0"
source_re,3421,1,1000.0000,,"Container",,"Stock RE : 1500"
source_sx,3421,1,0.0000,,"Container",,"Stock SX : 0"
source_yt,3421,1,1000.0000,,"Container",,"Stock YT : 1000"
source_re_pro,3421,1,500.0000,,"Container",,"Stock RE : 1500"
```

This wrong merged quantities is loaded by a custom GetSalableQuantityDataBySku that extends `\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku`

And i'm trying to make that either an sql request to fix this quantity issue or to fix the custom method, sadly, I haven't succeeded to get the real quantities on my own.

For the full vision of the issue this is what I have on the custom class

```
public function execute(string $sku): array
{
    $stockInfo = [];
    $stockIds = $this->getAssignedStockIdsBySku->execute($sku);
    if (count($stockIds)) {
        foreach ($stockIds as $stockId) {
            $stockId = (int)$stockId;
            $stock = $this->stockRepository->get($stockId);
            $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute($sku, $stockId);
            $isManageStock = $stockItemConfiguration->isManageStock();

            $salesChannelCodes = [];
            foreach($stock->getExtensionAttributes()->getSalesChannels() as $salesChannel) {
                $salesChannelCodes[] = $salesChannel->getCode();
            }

            $stockInfo[] = [
                'sales_channel_codes' => $salesChannelCodes,
                'stock_name' => $stock->getName(),
                'qty' => $isManageStock ? $this->getProductSalableQty->execute($sku, $stockId) : null,
                'manage_stock' => $isManageStock,
            ];
        }
    }
    return $stockInfo;
}
```

Thanks for your assistance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stock were configured by website instead of store, so the source_re and the source_re_pro had the same assigned stock id. Then, creating new stocks and sales channel made the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can export store stock too insted of export product